# Regarding the physical significance of the eigenvalues of the permutation operator

Tags: quantum-mechanics, symmetry, observables

Is the permutation operator an observable? I know that it is Hermitian* and unitary. If yes, what is the physical quantity that corresponds to the eigenvalues of this operator?

If we apply the permutation operator to a fermionic wavefunction, we get the same wavefunction back with a negative sign. Both the wavefunctions correspond to the same physical state, with a difference in phase. But the phase factor is not an observable, right? Or can it be deduced using interference experiments?

---

By permutation operator I mean the following. Consider two particles (may be non-identical) with spin $s$ such that their individual state spaces be isomorphic. One particle is in the $i$-th state and the other in the $j$-th state. The permutation operator $P$ swaps the two particles.

The Hilbert spaces of the particles are $\mathcal{H}_1$ and $\mathcal{H}_2$. The Hilbert of the system is given by $\mathcal{H}_1 \otimes \mathcal{H}_2$. $$|i, j\rangle := |i\rangle \otimes |j\rangle \in \mathcal{H}_1 \otimes \mathcal{H}_2$$ and $$P|i, j\rangle := |j, i\rangle = P(|i\rangle \otimes |j\rangle) = |j\rangle \otimes |i\rangle.$$ Also, $|j\rangle \otimes |i\rangle \in \mathcal{H}_1 \otimes \mathcal{H}_2$ as both the Hilbert spaces are isomorphic.

Reference:

Claude Cohen-Tannoudji; Bernard Diu; Franck Laloë (4 December 2019). Quantum Mechanics, Volume 2: Angular Momentum, Spin, and Approximation Methods. Wiley. ISBN 978-3-527-34554-0. ch. XIV, sec. B. Permutation operators, p. 1425.

*Let us assume that both the Hilbert spaces are finite-dimensional so that the distinction between Hermitian, self-adjoint and symmetric operators doesn't matter.

Comment: I think that the permutation operator acts on the tensor product of the individual spaces and its eigenvalues are +1 and -1; +1 corresponding to the bosonic, symmetric eigenvectors and -1 corresponding to the fermionic, anti-symmetric eigenvectors. Please correct me if I am wrong somewhere.

Comment: I deleted my request-for-clarification comment because I think the question is clear now.

Comment: Is the observable of $P$ not the parity of the state? The parity is $-1$ if the state describes a Fermion and $+1$ if it describes a Boson. See also [Exchange Operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exchange_operator).